# css flexbox change column direction to row

Tags: css, flexbox

I am currently having a column layout property.

For one of the class I want it be stacked in row.

Below is the html

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.weather-card {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.weather-list {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.week-item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <div class="weather-card">
    <span> <h2>Singapore  </h2><span>
          <span> 28&deg </span>
  </div>


  <div class="weather-list"> //items below should be shown one beside other
    <div class="week-item">
      <span> Monday </span>
      <span> 25&deg </span>
    </div>
    <div class="week-item">
      <span> Tue </span>
      <span> 35&deg </span>
    </div>
    <div class="week-item">
      <span> Wed </span>
      <span> 45&deg </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week-graph">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above markup the items in class Weather-list should be shown side by side. And when using mobile they should be shows one below other.

Comment: Just add display:flex to weather-list element [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVZOrE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVZOrE)

Answer (score 1):

You have to flex the .weather-list too. Flex only works for child elements of the flex parrent

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.weather-card {
  margin-top:20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.weather-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.week-item{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <div class="weather-card">
    <span> <h2>Singapore  </h2><span>
      <span> 28&deg </span>
  </div>


      <div class="weather-list">    
        <div class="week-item">
            <span> Monday </span> 
          <span> 25&deg </span> 
        </div>
        <div  class="week-item">
            <span> Tue </span> 
          <span> 35&deg </span> 
        </div>
        <div class="week-item">
            <span> Wed </span> 
          <span> 45&deg </span> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="week-graph">
      </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a nested flexbox, which is that .main-container is a parent flexbox and .weeather-list is a child flexbox. Adding a line in .weather-list can implement it.

```
.weather-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```